# How do you refer to the python script that you are programming inside the code without filenames? (read the description)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do not know how else to describe the question in words, so let me show you what I mean.
I have a file called "pugs.py". I am making it for other people so they might change the name for it, but I need the file to be able to refer to itself inside of the code. I could make sure it is always name, but I don't want that. So, how would I exactly refer to my "pugs.py" without saying "pugs.py", but instead something like "os.thisfile"?

Answer (score 2):

Python scripts and modules have a bit of information preloaded in their global namespace. `__file__` should give the filename.

```
import os
print(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `__name__` variable to get the file name in python if it is not called directly, else you can check [tdelaney's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72372079/10212936) answer for better suggestion.

Comment: Not if its a script, then its named `__main__`.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for the suggestion!